# Format when exporting data from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I created a code that copies the data of an Access table and pastes it on an Excel spreadsheet, but I need the first row to be in a different format (with an extensible option menu like in Access).

I mean, this is my first row:
[image: this]

And this is what I would like it to be: 
[image: this]

The objects are created with:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";" 

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1", cn, , , adCmdText
```

This is the part of the code where I paste the headers:

```
For intColIndex = 0 To (rs.Fields.Count - 1) 

    TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name 

Next
```

And then I paste the data with:

```
TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

---

Another thing I would also like to change is the width of the cells, because when I paste the Access data all the cells are of the same width and it looks awful. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to import from Excel.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    TargetRange.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).NAME
    TargetRange.Offset(0, i).Columns.AutoFit 'Autosize column
Next
With Application.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(1, TargetRange.CurrentRegion, , , 1) 'xlSrcRange, xlYes
    .Name = "MyTable"
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
End With
```

This formats as a table (with those dropdown arrows) and autoresizes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to have that arrow in the upper cells that says: "Sort A-Z, Sort Z-A, Find.." and those things like in Pivot Tables or in Access. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following

```
With TargetRange.Resize(,rs.Fields.Count)
    .Interior.Color = vbBlack
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End with
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to have that arrow in the upper cells that says: "Sort A-Z, Sort Z-A, Find.." and those things like in Pivot Tables or in Access. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you mention arrows in the upper cells, I think you're talking about adding a filter. Is this what you had in mind?

```
 TargetRange.AutoFilter
```